# Displaying image with php

Tags: php, image, corruption

I have a script which displays images like this:

```
header("Content-Type: image/{$ext}");
```

readfile($image->path);

This has worked fine for weeks and now suddenly it has stopped working. The response header looks fine (`Content-Type: image/jpg`), I have no ending php-tag and I have made no changes to my code, server- or php-setup which could have caused this to malfunction. Does anyone have a clue as to what may be going wrong?

Thanks!

======================

## UPDATE

The image doesn't display although you can download it (file->save as) and save it to computer. Openeing it locally though won't work either which leads me to think that the image has been corrupted somehow. Anyone experienced something similar? I'm thinking maybe som php errors/warnings get injected into the stream and corrupts the image.

Comment: What happens? Have you looked into the source code of the served image to see whether there are any error messages?

Comment: The src of the image is printed to screen, that's all. No error messages in apache log, no php error messages. If i dump the contents of the file to screen I get the raw image data, but alas nothing happens when setting the header and using readfile()

Comment: try another browser, see if that works

Comment: I've tried that (safari, firefox, opera, chrome), but no luck

Answer (score 0):

The right content-type for JPG images is "Content-type: image/jpeg".

Note that the T of type is lower case.

**UPDATE**

I don't know if it will be useful but try something like this:

```
$info=pathinfo($image->path);
$ext=strtolower($info["extension"]);
if($ext=="jpg") $ext="jpeg";
header("Content-type: image/$ext");
imagejpeg(imagecreatefromjpeg($image->path));
```

Comment: Actually, I think it's capital T, but in the past it worked with both lowercase c and t, but wither way it's not working

Comment: Wow, have you read my code? 

$info = pathinfo($image->path);
$ext = strtolower($info['extension']);
$image->ext == 'jpg' ? $image->ext = 'jpeg' : null;
header("Content-Type: {$image->ext}");
readfile($image->path);

Tried imagejpeg(imagecreatefromjpeg($image->path)) but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

One source of possible issues is that the MIME type for JPEG images is `image/jpeg`, not `image/jpg`.  This is a case where the type doesn't agree with the fairly-common, 3-character version of the file extension.

Comment: Tried that, but no dice. I have the same problem with image/png, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

- File is to big
- File path causing problems

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding the header and file path and seeing what happens? Try a small jpg file with a simple name like image.jpg

Comment: Did that now, no luck. This has to be server-related, there's nothing wrong with the code, and it has been working fine for 4-5 weeks now. Truly weird.

Comment: If you inspect the response (view source or output file in text editor) do you see any warnings/errors? Or is it a 0 byte output file?

Comment: Nothing in page source ("view -> page source" menu option is disabled); firebug displays this:
<img src="http://huset.dev/images/get/id/5CCCCN" alt="http://huset.dev/images/get/id/5CCCCN">

Comment: Can you 'Save File As'? Or wget? and then view the content.

Comment: Yes, I can 'File save as' and get it with curl. File contains binary data, but I can't open it with Preview ("It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.")

Comment: Strange, opening the same (the original that is) image on my local drive works fine, at what point does it get corrupted when serving from apache? The filesize of the downloaded image is the same as the original.

Comment: Try opening the downloaded file with Notepad (or some other text editor) and see if there's any garbage at the start of the file (like a PHP warning/error). It may be a perfectly fine image, but has been corrupted because PHP added some text before the image data started.

Comment: The downloaded file is actually 1 byte bigger than the original, so there is obviously something there. Strange thing is I checked out the source on two other machines and there everything worked fine, same revision and all. I'll try to track down the offending byte. Thanks for all help!